# converting class 'tuple' in python to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, dataset, finance

Am applying some method / property out of a custom lib in python `mlfinlab`.
When I apply this calculation ([here is the link](https://mlfinlab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/implementations/data_structures.html#information-driven-bars)). Under `get_ema_dollar_imbalance_bars` , then am getting back an output with

`<class 'tuple'>` as a type of the object, then towards the end of the output space I get the below

```
 [4798 rows x 10 columns],
 Empty DataFrame
 Columns: []
 Index: [] , dtype=object)
```

what am trying to do is to convert it into a pandas dataframe.
I have tried different methods around including transforming it first to a NumPy array then I can get in to pandas df format, but it is still not working.

Any help/guidance is appreciated and welcomed on your part.
I have included some snapshots as well.

best regards

Comment: This is not how you should ask a question, it is mostly unreadable, kindly see how to ask, then edit the question.

Comment: actually am new to the platform , and secondly I could not find a way to add snap shoots /links so that you can understand very quick , I have been in to other forums , including github , but no answer was given till the moment , I don't know how better can I explain !thanks for the comment any way

Comment: In order to add snapshots. under the Body field (after clicking on edit), on the right-hand top corner, click on show formatting tips, there you will find an option to add images.

Meanwhile, I guess others would have submitted edit requests by now, kindly accept them, so that we can help you.

Comment: thanks guys , resolved , weirdly enough by just tacking [0] right after your tuple object , now you simply apply type(tuple[0]) then it provides the type as a data frame directly without any transformation , how do I close the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

**First option:**

1. Convert your tuple to a list with:

```
    lst = list(yourtuple)
```

2. Convert to a dataframe:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
```

**Second Option:**

I can't see the formatting of your tuple, but assuming you need more than one column, and your tuple is structured in a way where it's ((col1,entry1,entry2),(col2,entry1,entry2)), you can do the following:

1. Create a dictionary:

```
    newdict = dict(yourtuple)
```

2. Convert to a dataframe:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame([newdict])
```

Comment: Hi guys , while trying the above suggestions , I get using the 1-st option , an empty df again which shows only 0 ,1 as headers of the columns with only two rows , as for the 2nd option I get the following value error " ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 10; 2 is required" it is worthwhile to indicate that the original class 'tuple' object already shows 10 columns including data_time as one of the columns with values of the rows up to 4775